# First html helper generates client-side validation attributes, while the second one doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unobtrusive-javascript

Let's say I have this model:

```
public class Person
{
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

And whis this codes, I am trying to render `input` with `check` type:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsApproved)
@Html.CheckBox("IsApproved")
```

But, the results are different:

```
// CheckBoxFor result
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The IsApproved field is required." id="IsApproved" name="IsApproved" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="IsApproved" type="hidden" value="false">

// CheckBox result
<input id="IsApproved" name="IsApproved" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="IsApproved" type="hidden" value="false">
```

***How and why***, the first one generates attributes for client-side validation, while the other didn't?

***Update:***

After swapping the order of `@Html.CheckBoxFor` and `@Html.CheckBox`, the order of markup elements didn't change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `CheckBox()` helper does not render the`data-val` attributes because the form has already rendered `CheckBoxFor()` for the same property. If you swap the order, the `data-val` attributes would be rendered for `CheckBox()` (and not for `CheckBoxFor()`).

My understanding is this would cause a potential (duplication) problem with jquery.validation.unobtrusive when parsing the form.

The html helpers for controls internally call the `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method of `HtmlHelper`. [From the source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs) (my emphasis)

> Only render attributes if unobtrusive client-side validation is enabled, **and then only if we've never rendered validation for a field with this name in this form**. Also, if there's no form context, then we can't render the attributes (we'd have no  to attach them to)

```
public IDictionary<string, object> GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(string name, ModelMetadata metadata)
{
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation. This is an answer.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, Sorry for distrubing again. Several days ago I have posted one question about one problem which I metAsp.net MVC. Have youu any idea about it? Could you please look at it. Here is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31492648/best-practice-for-using-interface-type-as-model-in-view-and-use-real-type-attrib).

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev, No time now, but I'll take a look tomorrow morning :)

Comment: :) Ok, sorry for disturbing again. Thanks.