# Rendering Html Control while debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2013, immediate-window

I am using `.NET4.5`, `MVC5`, `C#` and `Visual Studio 2013`. I have ViewModel that has collection of `UserInformation`.

```
public class UserInformation
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name"), Display(Name = "First name")]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^ *?[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-_']*$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter First name with letters only")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a firstname with no more than 20 characters")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your surname"), Display(Name = "Surname")]
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^ *?[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-_']*$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter Surname with letters only")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a surname with no more than 20 characters")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

When rendering users on page Customer0 gets data annotations added while Customer1 does not.

Customer 0:

```
<input name="Customers[0].Firstname" class="tooltip form-control input valid" data-val="true" data-val-length="Please enter a firstname with no more than 20 characters" data-val-length-max="20" data-val-regex="Please enter First name with letters only" data-val-regex-pattern="^ *?[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-_']*$" data-val-required="Please enter your first name" id="Customers[0].Firstname" maxlength="20" placeholder="Name" tabindex="" type="text" value="Matas">
```

Customer 1:

```
<input name="Customers[1].Firstname" class="tooltip form-control input valid" id="Customers[1].Firstname" maxlength="20" placeholder="Name" tabindex="" type="text" value="sss">
```

I have managed to trace to the point where it get's rendered on the page that anotations are still there

From immediate window:

```
    var attr3 = Model.Item1.GetType().GetProperties()[1].GetCustomAttributes(true);
{object[5]}
    [0]: {System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute}
    [1]: {System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute}
    [2]: {System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute}
    [3]: {System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute}
    [4]: {System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute}
```

To investigate further (following the string) next step is to render both controls immediately to see what I am getting.

When I try to render controls in Immediate Window

`var s = Html.TextEditor(o => o.Item1.Firstname, new TextEditParameters { Id = string.Format("Customers[{0}].Firstname", Model.Item2), Name = string.Format("Customers[{0}].Firstname", Model.Item2), CssClasses = "input", Placeholder = "Firstname", Type = HtmlExtensions.TextEditorType.OnlyTextBox });`

I obviously get

> Expression cannot contain lambda expressions

**Edit:**
Mechanism that generates control

In main partial:

Customer 0:

```
   @Html.Partial("Unit/_Customer", new Tuple<UserInformation, int>(Model.Customers[0], 0))
```

Customer 1:

```
   @if (Model.Customers.Count > 1)
   {
   <li>
       <h1 class="h1--blue">Your partners details</h1>
   </li>
   Html.RenderPartial("Unit/_Customer", new Tuple<UserInformation, int>(Model.Customers[1], 1));
  }
```

In _Customer partial:

```
<div class="split-input--left">
    @Html.TextEditor(o => o.Item1.Firstname, new TextEditParameters { Name = string.Format("Customers[{0}].Firstname", Model.Item2), Id = string.Format("Customers[{0}].Firstname", Model.Item2), CssClasses = "input ", Placeholder = "Name", Type = HtmlExtensions.TextEditorType.OnlyTextBox })
</div>
```

Then in html extensions:

```
  public static MvcHtmlString TextEditor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, TextEditParameters textEditParameters)
    {
        string editor;
        switch (textEditParameters.Type)
        {
            case TextEditorType.Currency:
                editor = "Inputs/CurrencyPrefixTextInput";
                break;
            case TextEditorType.Autocomplete:
                editor = "Inputs/AutocompleteTextInput";
                break;
            case TextEditorType.Email:
                editor = "Inputs/EmailTextInput";
                break;
            case TextEditorType.Tel:
                editor = "Inputs/TelTextInput";
                break;
            case TextEditorType.OnlyTextBox:
                editor = "Inputs/TextInputOnly";
                break;
            case TextEditorType.OnlyTextBoxCurrency:
                editor = "Inputs/TextInputOnlyCurrency";
                break;
            default:
                editor = "Inputs/TextInput";
                break;
        }

        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        var maxLength = 4096;
        if (member != null)
        {
            var stringLengthAttr =
                (member.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (StringLengthAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute);

            if (stringLengthAttr != null)
                maxLength = stringLengthAttr.MaximumLength;
        }

        var model = new
        {
            InputFormat = textEditParameters.Format,
            HasHelp = textEditParameters.HasHelpText,
            UniqueId = textEditParameters.Id ?? GetHtmlifiedId(html.IdFor(expression).ToString()),
            PlaceHolder = textEditParameters.Placeholder,
            MaxLength = maxLength,
            textEditParameters.Annotation,
            textEditParameters.HasTick,
            textEditParameters.TabIndex,
            textEditParameters.CssClasses,
            textEditParameters.Name,
            RangeErrorMessage = textEditParameters is CurrencyTextEditParameters ? ((CurrencyTextEditParameters) textEditParameters).RangeErrorMessage : null,
            RangeValidation = textEditParameters is CurrencyTextEditParameters ? ((CurrencyTextEditParameters)textEditParameters).RangeValidation : null,
            RegexValidation = textEditParameters is CurrencyTextEditParameters ? ((CurrencyTextEditParameters)textEditParameters).RegexValidation : null,
            RegexErrorMessage = textEditParameters is CurrencyTextEditParameters ? ((CurrencyTextEditParameters)textEditParameters).RegexErrorMessage : null,
            IsRequired = textEditParameters is CurrencyTextEditParameters && ((CurrencyTextEditParameters)textEditParameters).IsRequired,
            RequiredErrorMessage = textEditParameters is CurrencyTextEditParameters ? ((CurrencyTextEditParameters)textEditParameters).RequiredErrorMessage : null,
        };

        return html.EditorFor(expression, editor, model);
    }
```

Then it gets passed into TextInputOnly.cshtml partial:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, @ViewData["InputFormat"].ToString(), new { Name = ViewData["Name"], @class = string.Format("tooltip form-control {0}", ViewData["CssClasses"]), id = ViewData["UniqueId"].ToString(), @placeholder = ViewData["PlaceHolder"].ToString(), maxlength = ViewData["MaxLength"].ToString(), tabindex = ViewData["TabIndex"] })

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m, null, new {@class = "field-validation-error", data_valmsg_for = ViewData["Name"]})
```

This is where I am doing debugging of attributes still being there.

**How would I go around rendering control whilst debugging in Visual Studio 2013?**

Comment: Show how you are generating the inputs in the view. It appears you manually attempting to override the `name` attribute instead of using a `for` loop

Comment: @StephenMuecke done, please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: Oh dear :) Not really sure what your trying to achieve with this but the reason is that your generating a form controls for a property with the same name and then trying to fake model binding by changing the `name` attribute. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047930/html-checkboxfor-generates-client-side-validation-attributes-while-html-check/29048385#29048385) explains why the `data-val` attributes are only rendered for the first control.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am just playing with cards I was given (I think I am loosing too). :) Thanks for reference I am now working in this direction.