# Mvc Core: Validation attributes are generated once for dublicated names

Tags: validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, tag-helpers

This is a question just like an [old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047930/first-html-helper-generates-client-side-validation-attributes-while-the-second) but in the old one, the reason for that is marked as the answer.

My page, there is a form that contains several items. Each item contains a few elements so their name is duplicated.

```html
<form ...>
    .....
    <table class="details">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Prop1</th>
                <th>Prop2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var item in Model.Items)
            {
               @await Html.PartialAsync("partial-view-name", detail)
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ...
</form>
```

The partial

```html
....
<tr>
   <td><input asp-for="Prop1" /></td>
   <td><input asp-for="Prop2" /></td>
</tr>
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6584) this is the designed behavior, but I wondered if there is any way to override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to add a prefix to the HTML fields so the name would be different in the iterations.

```html
@{ ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = Model.ID; }
<tr>
   <td><input asp-for="Prop1"/></td>
   <td><input asp-for="Prop2"/></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is how you are rendering out each object to the screen. If you apply the logic below it should render correctly and also bind back to the list correctly on submit.

```
@for (int i=0; i< Model.Items.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="text-center">
       <label asp-for="@Model.Items[i].Prop1"></label>
       <input asp-for="@Model.Items[i].Prop1" />
       <label asp-for="@Model.Items[i].Prop2"></label>
       <input asp-for="@Model.Items[i].Prop2" />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you @eVolve, you are absolutely right. I tried to simplify the scenario. The items are in a partial view. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Okay so why don't you pass in your list into the partial and then do the loop i've advised above in the partial rather than your main page

Comment: I use a framework that generates the views and controllers, this tool may generate div instead of a table and use the partial view for different purposes.